# Looping with Edge Animate - nested movie clip not playing after loop

Tags: javascript, html, animation, adobe-edge

I am creating an animation for the first time in Edge Animate.

First, I would like the animation to loop. Then when I get that right, I want it to loop and stop after 30 seconds.

To loop it, I have added a trigger action at the end of the animation, with the code looking like this:
this.play(0);

BUT when it loops, it fails to play the nested movie clips - so it only loops the stage, and randomly shows one of the movie clips later on.

This seems so simple, but I can't get it to loop correctly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Nici

Comment: Please provide sample code using JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly  Brian! :)

Here is the link generated from jsfiddle:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/jgxsh1t3/)